# migration from http to https in wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, https, wildfly, java-ee-7

I want to migrate from http to https in wildfly 19.1

after setup all configuration from this tutorials https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-ssl-https-on-jboss-wildfly-application-server-fde6288a0f40 i have trouble :

when my application server startsup try to load all of pages.

note: my project is a huge project with heavy queries and this action take a lot of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the `Standalone.xml` we should disable the `enable-http2="true"` of this line:

```
<https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="false"\>
```